# Start an application from the dock within a specific directory

Tags: macos, emacs

I have an application (Emacs) in the dock that is apparently starting in / (the root folder).
Can I configure it to start in $HOME instead?  e.g., looking for the equivalent of shortcut properties in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your `.emacs` file, insert:

```
(cd "~/")
```

---

```
cd is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `files.el'.

(cd DIR)

Make DIR become the current buffer's default directory.
If your environment includes a `CDPATH' variable, try each one of
that list of directories (separated by occurrences of
`path-separator') when resolving a relative directory name.
The path separator is colon in GNU and GNU-like systems.
```

Comment: Thanks you are correct this does work for Emacs, but I am still interested in a solution that would work with other apps as well.